# Combining multiple queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have code that I've written in an ORM syntax. It reads blog comments data from a file, and inserts them into `blogs` and `comments` tables. **I'd like to take this ORM code back to mysql, because I need to combine as many queries as possible into a single query, and this optimization wouldn't be easy in the ORM language. The reason I need this optimization is because I'm working with a remote server, so the fewer the queries, the better.** I wrote the code below in mysql pseudo-code, because I somewhat forgot mysql.

This is the comments file that contains all the comments for all the blogs. `from blog url` tells me which blog this comment belongs to.

```
comment text               from blog url
------------------------------------------
first comment text         first-blog-url
second comment text        first-blog-url
third comment text         first-blog-url
fourth comment text        blog-2-url
fifth comment text         blog-2-url
sixth comment text         3rd-blog-url
```

This is the ORM code that I use to process the file. (at the very bottom, I added the description of the tables).

```
//I read a comment from the comments file, `comment text` and `from blog url`

//does a blog exist that has 'link' that matches 'from blog url'
$blog = //SELECT FROM blogs where 'link' has value 'first-blog-url'

//if it doesn't exist, create it
if($blog == null){
    $blog = INSERT INTO blogs a new record and set 'link' to 'first-blog-url'
}

//then read the id of the (existing or just-created) blog row
$blog_id = $blog->getId();

//then use the $blog_id to insert the comment into the 'comments' table.

//does this comment text already exist for this blog id?
$comment = SELECT FROM comments where `commenttext' has value 'whatever comment text' and 'blogid' has value $blog_id

//if it doesn't exist, create it
if($comment == null){
    $comment = INSERT INTO comments a new record and set 'commenttext' to 'the comment text' and 'blogid' to $blog_id.
}

$comment_id = $comment->getId();
```

**So my question: is it possible to write this in a single mysql query?**

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2278838/710316) but it doesn't fully solve my problem, and I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to do it.

The 2 tables are `blogs` and `comments` where each row in `comments` has a field `blogid` that links it to the right blog in `blogs`. So it's basically a 1:many relationship where each `blog` row can be linked to many `comment` rows. They look like this:

```
blogs:

id        link                  other fields
--------------------------------------------
1         first-blog-url
2         blog-2-url
3         3rd-blog-url

comments:

id        commenttext     blogid
-----------------------------
1         random          1
2         comment         1
3         goes            1
4         here            2
5         any             2 
6         thing           3
```

Comment: TO insert into two tables do you need at least two sql statements (one by table). Do you know it? Otherwise, a store procedure or trigger is needed. Is a procedure or trigger a valid solution for you?

Comment: @danihp my main goal is to contact that database server once if possible. So I'm OK with anything that helps me do that.

Comment: @danihp I should point out that the 2 queries I'm trying to combine are related, but not identical. The second query just uses the `blog_id` from the first query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this technique to insert a row if not exists:

```
INSERT INTO blogs (link)
select 'first-blog-url' 
from dual
where not exists
( select 1
  from blogs
  where  link = 'first-blog-url'
);
```

As you can see, select clause will return a only one row with data to be inserted only when not yet exists in database. [You can test it at SQLFIDDLE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c327/1/0)

To insert into `comment` table you can use same technique. You can get `Blog id` for second query with [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/getting-unique-id.html) if inserted is dued (if not, you need a new query).

This is only a point to start, perhaps you can reduce to 3 your 4 queries. Any comment are welcome to figure up final solution.

As you know, MySQL don't has MERGE statement. I think that [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) don't match your requeriments.

Comment: I'm wondering, what is `from dual` Is this a misnamed table, or a special keyword?

Comment: So is it possible to further nest the comment insertion, so that both blog insertion and comment insertion are in the same query?

Comment: YOu need a insert statement for each table. You can't do both inserts in the same statement. Perhaps do you want to encapsulate all code into a [store procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx).